# How are numbers pronounced in (movie) titles? (i.e. ジョーズ３)

Tags: pronunciation, readings, numbers

For example, ジョーズ３ (i.e. "Jaws Three") is in a list of movies.  Would the "3" be pronounced "さん"?  Typically, counter words follow after a number in Japanese.  And sometimes the number's reading changes depending on the counter.  For example, 「じゅうがつ・とおか」. But this is a katakana word. Is there a pattern followed for titles?

How would a native Japanese speaker pronounce a title such as this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most natural reading in this case would be the transliteration of the English reading of the number

1. ワン
2. ツー or トゥー
3. スリー
4. フォー
5. ファイブ
6. シックス
7. セブン
8. エイト
9. ナイン
10. テン
11. イレブン
12. トゥエルブ
13. サーティーン

etc.

For example, 『オーシャンズ[11]{イレブン}』 or indeed 『ジョーズ[3]{スリー}』.

Answer (score 3):

Usually it is pronounced in katakana English

Examples:
2 days: トゥー・デイズ
Super 8: スーパーエイト
Ten: テン
Terminator 2: ターミネーター トゥー
Ocean's 11: オーシャンズ イレブン

[https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/2_days_トゥー・デイズ](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/2_days_%E3%83%88%E3%82%A5%E3%83%BC%E3%83%BB%E3%83%87%E3%82%A4%E3%82%BA)
[https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/SUPER8/スーパーエイト](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/SUPER8/%E3%82%B9%E3%83%BC%E3%83%91%E3%83%BC%E3%82%A8%E3%82%A4%E3%83%88)
[https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/テン_(映画)](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%86%E3%83%B3_(%E6%98%A0%E7%94%BB))
https://youtu.be/DoIETt21P7g?t=40s
[https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/オーシャンズ11](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%AA%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A3%E3%83%B3%E3%82%BA11)

Comment: `ターミネーター トゥー` じゃなくて 「ターミネーター ツー」って読みますよね、普通？ そのリンク先のようつべのビデオでも「ターミネーターツー」って言ってますし。「ジョーズ２」「ダイ・ハード２」とかも、「ジョーズツー」「ダイハードツー」って読むでしょう？