# How to pronounce "2" in はやぶさ2 (spacecraft / mission)

Tags: pronunciation, numbers

I'm a beginner. I was watching news about JAXA's はやぶさ2 mission and I think it is pronounced はやぶさ つ. Can someone please confirm that "2" is pronounced "つ" and explain why.

Comment: Related/duplicate: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/61676/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/69165/9831

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're hearing is likely just the Japanese way of saying the English "two"—which sounds like the つ sound because that "t" sound in words like "two" and "two" doesn't exist in Japanese.

Some people may also call the spacecraft the はやぶさ2号, or "Hayabusa 2-go," which I believe is the official name.